# What is wrong with this code? When it opens up in the native maps app it takes me to a random location

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

Followed a video tutorial. When i build this app and hit the directions button it takes me to a random area instead of the coordinates provided. I am a beginner. Also, is there a way to pass in the locations address instead of coordinates, or should i just use the coordinates. Thanks for any responses. I am using Swift 5 in xCode 10. I changed the coordinate for privacy.

```
@IBAction func directionsClinic(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let latitude:CLLocationDegrees = 38.465492
    let longitude:CLLocationDegrees = 91.338905

    let regionDistance:CLLocationDistance = 1000;
    let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, 
          longitude)

    let regionSpan = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinates, 
          latitudinalMeters: regionDistance, longitudinalMeters: 
          regionDistance)
    let options = [MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey: 
          NSValue(mkCoordinate:regionSpan.center), 
          MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey: NSValue(mkCoordinateSpan: 
          regionSpan.span)]
    let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinates)
    let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark:placemark)

    mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: options)

}
```

i have just tried a few different youtube videos guides, but most were a year+ old and im not sure if the code has changed

Expected the location of the coordinates to show up in the native iphone maps app, instead it was taking me to a place on the other side of the globe.

Comment: Did you ever get a resolution to this? When I run your code using Xcode 11, it goes to a consistent place in Apple Maps

Comment: Yeah i think i had the coordinates set up backwards

Answer (score -1):

You can try this to open with a specific address:

```
let baseUrl: String = "http://maps.apple.com/?q="
let encodedName = theAddress.addingPercentEncoding( withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) ?? ""
let finalUrl = baseUrl + encodedName
if let url = NSURL(string: finalUrl) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
}
```

The Maps app will intercept the request and open the app.